# Pandas Pivot chart with filtering

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly

I  have a data frame as shown below.It's name is 'df_IBIAS_mode1_FUN'

[image]

I need to plot a pivot chart with index='Device_ID'', columns='Temp(deg)', values='ibias_post_trim[MHz]' **for all values of Supply[V]=2.5**.

Below is my code for making the pivot table.

```
df_IBIAS_mode1_FUN[df_IBIAS_mode1_FUN.Supply[V] == 2.5].pivot_table(index='Device_ID', columns='Temp(deg)', values='ibias_post_trim[MHz')
```

This coding throwing an error as shown below.May I know where I went wrong.

```
*AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Supply'*
```

Comment: Can you please share (dummy) data for reproducibility? Can be done by adding the output of `print(df_IBIAS_mode1_FUN.to_csv(index=False))` to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use quotations to access the column, as the column name contains square brackets. You are also missing a square bracket towards the end:

```
df_IBIAS_mode1_FUN[df_IBIAS_mode1_FUN["Supply[V]"] == 2.5].pivot_table(index='Device_ID', columns='Temp(deg)', values='ibias_post_trim[MHz]')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `['Supply[V]']` to access `Supply[V]` column

```py
df_IBIAS_mode1_FUN[df_IBIAS_mode1_FUN['Supply[V]'] == 2.5].pivot_table(index='Device_ID', columns='Temp(deg)', values='ibias_post_trim[MHz')
```